# Android MVP - RxJava and retrofit - best approach

Tags: android, mockito, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-mvp

I'm figuring out how to develop an Android app, using MVP, RxJava2 and retrofit.

In my presenter, here is the code:

```
public void loadData() {

    compositeDisposable.dataModelRepository.getDataList().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(mainScheduler).subscribe(new Consumer<List<Data>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(List<Data> dataList) throws Exception {
            if (!dataList.isEmpty())
                view.displayData(dataList);
            else
                view.displayEmpty();
        }
    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(throwable.toString());
            view.displayError("boooom");
        }
    });
}
```

Retrofit interface has been defined in the following way:

```
@GET("/fooURL")
Single<List<Data>> getDataList();
```

And the repository is just

```
public Single<List<Data>> getDataList() {
    return retrofitApi.getDataList();
}
```

And it is working fine. Question is as follows: my intention is to fetch network data only when data is not available locally, in db.

Having this in mind, is it correct that schedulers are managed in the presenter? Or should they be managed in the Repository?

My guess is that presenter is the correct place, as it creates a thread so repository can do its stuff sequentially (fetch db, if nothing, then fetch network/cache; return data wherever it has been fetched), and when data is provided, notify the view inside the accept method of the Consumer.

Is it correct? Or should it be done in a different way?

Another point is: how can i test using Mockito the repository? The dataModelRepository.getDataList() method i mean? Not sure how to do any Assert for Single objects...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at concat. This can be used to consume the first observable (locally) and if it emit no items it consume the second (network)

Comment: there is no correct way in MVP. People do whatever fits for them. It's all opinion based

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TimCastelijns agree with you, I'd just like to see different points of view. As you can see, this approach could have problems with unit test, as I'm not sure how we could validate the Repository... maybe somebody proposes something different that fits in a better way

Comment: unfortunately this is not the place to ask for different point of views. Opinion based questions are off topic here

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to offload all business logic that is related to fetching, retrieving data to a central repository.

One way to achieve somewhat similar to what you have described is to use a concat operator.

```
Observable<List<Data>> getData() {
    return Observable
        .concat(localRepository.getData(), remoteRepository.getData())
        .first();
}
```

This will try to get data from your local repository first and if it has no data it will make a network request.

I assume your local and remote repositories will be observed on a new thread, but if you need to perform any action on the UI, simply subscribe on a main thread in your presenter.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, in fact, I have already created a repository class, that is, at the present moment, acting as a proxy (it receives the getData request, and sends the request to network). Next move will be to create that concat action for trying to fetch initially from database. Thanks!